# Does Spell-Vamp work with Smite? And is it useful on AP champs?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does Spell-Vamp work on smite? If it does, will it be good on champs like Kennen, Morde or any other AP champ that gets spell vamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just tried it vs bots. It works and heals good I think. I don't know why people with spell vamp don't use it, I think its really good when fighting and there are some enemy minions nearby.

Comment: sweet :D . i wonder if we should post about it in LoL forums or keep to ourselves XD

Answer (score 2):

Smite does proc spell-vamp but honestly taking it solely for that purpose is a waste since as a AP carry you would probably want Flash+Ignite combo which is more beneficial regardless.

Comment: but if you use smite on a minion when you're fighting , you;ll get helped for a lot , maybe 150-200 maybe ?

Comment: @MastaMoMo Why not take heal instead? Heal's much better for team fights too.

Answer (score 0):

According to the League of Legends Wikia (http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Spell_vamp    *see the notes section) it should work with summoner's spells such as smite and ignite. In that case ignite would be more useful as you can use it on champions.

Answer (score 0):

It works out on Lee Sin's shield really well, and it has saved me some times :)

Comment: i havnt played lee sin yet , but how does it work with his shield skill :o

Comment: The second half of his W gives him spell vamp for a brief time.